# JMeter Summary Aggregate report - How to split Pass/Fail count and filter metrics only for successful samples

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm using the below command to generate the aggregate report which provides the count, median, 90th percentile, error rate etc.

```
call java %JAVAHEAP% -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar %JMETER_HOME%/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv summary_agg.csv --input-jtl steadystate.csv --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

However, it seems to be pulling the metrics even for the failed transactions also. For .e.g, the below line indicates that the transaction had a 68% failure rate but the count represents the number of calls including the failed transactions.

> sampler_label aggregate_report_count  average aggregate_report_median aggregate_report_90%_line   aggregate_report_min    aggregate_report_max    aggregate_report_error% aggregate_report_rate   aggregate_report_bandwidth  aggregate_report_stddev
>   UpdateCart    35652   1861    1526    2740    13  65047   64.35%  19.8    34  2118.83

My questions

- Does it calculate the response time metrics only for the successful
     samples or it includes all the samples including the failures?

  If yes, how can I generate a loadrunner like report. i.e., it should
     provide pass and fail count separately and should provide response
     time metrics only for successful samples

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. JMeter Aggregate report includes response time metrics for both pass and fail transactions into one.
2. You can use two separate aggregate report listeners to find out Pass and fail transactional metrics separately by applying Only Success and Errors in the checkbox.

Comment: On #2, I am not using the listener but the command line runner after the execution to create the summary aggregate report.